# C Why does scanf returns the false output

Tags: c, scanf

here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
CALCULATING INVERSE OF A MATRIX
*/
int main(){

    int matris[3][3];
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for (j=0;j<3;j++){
            scanf("%d", &matris);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i<3; i++){

        for (j=0;j<3;j++){

            printf("%d ", matris);
        }
    }

}
```

When i give the input as 1-9 numbers, i expect the program to print 3x3 matrix within 1-9 but it returns this output

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536 6487536
```

Where is my mistake? Thx for help

Comment: `scanf("%d", &matris);` -> `scanf("%d", &matris[i][j]);` (and similarly for the `printf`).

Comment: `matris` is an array, and as an array is decays to a pointer to its first element. This is what you print. And what you attempt to write to with your `scanf` call. You need to write to each and every element with `scanf` and then print each and every element, using indexing such as `matris[i][j]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%d", &matris);` is wrong as long as you want to write different data in different elements of the array `matris`.

`printf("%d ", matris);` is also wrong because you want to print out different values from different elements of the array `matris`.

Rather do it like that:

`scanf("%d",&matris[i][j]);`

and

`printf("%d",matris[i][j]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the address-of operator `&` on the base address of the 2D array (matris in this case), you should mark the exact address that you would like to get the number to it as people mentioned here `&matris[i][j]`, because each cell in this array has a different address. 
and in case of the `printf` you just printed the base address of the 2D array.